# When I press the keyboard delete key on a row in a datagridview then two rows dissappear

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, keyboard-events

On a form with a datagridview, and a drop-donwlist with distinct part numbers in it, when I press the delete key from the keyboard then the selected row in the dgv gets deleted but the first row is hidden from the dgv. I have to manually re-select the p/n from the drop-down list to see it again.  I also have a delete button on the form but that works perfectly and uses the same sub, DeleteCurrentRow.  Here is the KeyDown handler for the keyboard delete key:

```
Private Sub DGVCurrentPoints_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DGVCurrentPoints.KeyDown
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Delete Then
        DeleteCurrentRow()
    End If
End Sub
```

This sub, DeleteCurrentRow, is called if I press the delete key on the keyboard, or the Delete button on the form:

```
 Private Sub DeleteCurrentRow()
    If Trim(CollectionPntPNList.Text).Length = 0 OrElse (CurrentPriorPassRequirementId = 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing to delete." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Please select a Part Number from the drop-down list, then select any cell on the data grid view." & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "When the Delete button is pressed, the highlighted row will be deleted.",
                        "Nothing to delete",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Delete the highlighted record? (Yes/No)",
                        "Ok to delete?",
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If result = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CollectionPoints.sDeleteCollectionPointSet(CurrentPriorPassRequirementId)
        DisplayCurrentCollectionPoints()
        DGVCurrentPoints.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

CollectionPoints is a class, and DisplayCurrentCollectionPoints() is a local/private sub that is used to re-populate the dgv.  Here is DisplayCurrentCollectionPoints():

```
Private Sub DisplayCurrentCollectionPoints()
    Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection.FISSQLConnectionString)
    Dim objCommand As SqlCommand = objConn.CreateCommand
    Dim strSQL As New StringBuilder
    DGVCurrentPoints.DataSource = Nothing

    strSQL.Append("SELECT ")
    strSQL.Append("     ppr.PriorPassRequirementId AS [Row ID], ")
    strSQL.Append("     RTRIM(LTRIM(cp1.Description)) AS Description1, ")
    strSQL.Append("     ppr.CollectionPointId AS Point1, ")
    strSQL.Append("     RTrim(LTrim(cp2.Description)) AS Description2, ")
    strSQL.Append("       ppr.ReqPassedCollectionPointId AS Point2, ")
    strSQL.Append("ppr.Enabled, ")
    strSQL.Append("cp1.CollectionStep AS Step1, ")
    strSQL.Append("cp2.CollectionStep AS Step2 ")
    strSQL.Append("FROM ")
    strSQL.Append("     PriorPassRequirements AS ppr INNER JOIN ")
    strSQL.Append("       CollectionPoints AS cp1 ON ppr.CollectionPointId = cp1.CollectionPointId INNER JOIN ")
    strSQL.Append("       Products ON cp1.ProductIdValue = Products.ProductId INNER JOIN ")
    strSQL.Append("       CollectionPoints AS cp2 ON Products.ProductId = cp2.ProductIdValue ")
    strSQL.Append("         AND ppr.ReqPassedCollectionPointId = cp2.CollectionPointId ")
    strSQL.Append("WHERE ")
    strSQL.Append("     (ppr.CollectionPointId IN ")
    strSQL.Append("             (SELECT     cp.CollectionPointId ")
    strSQL.Append("             FROM ")
    strSQL.Append("                 CollectionPoints AS cp INNER JOIN ")
    strSQL.Append("                 Products AS p ON cp.ProductIdValue = p.ProductId ")
    strSQL.Append("             WHERE ")
    strSQL.Append("                 (p.PartNumber = N'" & Trim(CollectionPntPNList.Text) & "'))) ")
    strSQL.Append("ORDER BY Step1, Step2")
    objCommand.CommandText = strSQL.ToString

    Dim dtCurrPnts As New DataTable
    objConn.Open()
    dtCurrPnts.Load(objCommand.ExecuteReader)
    objConn.Dispose()
    With DGVCurrentPoints
        .DataSource = dtCurrPnts
        .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        .Columns("Row ID").Visible = True
        .Columns("Description1").ReadOnly = True
        .Columns("Point1").ReadOnly = True
        .Columns("Description2").ReadOnly = True
        .Columns("Point2").ReadOnly = True
        .Columns("Enabled").ReadOnly = False
    End With
End Sub
```

After the End Sub of the DGVCurrentPoints_KeyDown event, the first row in the dgv is hidden but not deleted. This is where I'd have to re-select the p/n from the drop-down.  What would cause the first row to be hidden when I use the keyboard delete key?  I use dgv.Refresh() but that doesn't appear to work.

---

Per the suggestion from Plutonix, I've added this sub to take care of the delete:

```
    Private Sub DGVCurrentPoints_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DGVCurrentPoints.KeyDown
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Delete Then
        e.Handled = True
        DeleteCurrentRow()
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DGV has can already delete the selected/current row in response to the Delete key.  So when a user presses Delete, DGV deletes one and you delete one.  This is also why the button works as expected.  The `AllowUserToDeleteRows` will prevent this so you can do it all in code, or add this:

```
If e.KeyValue = Keys.Delete Then 
    e.Handled = True         ' add
    DeleteCurrentRow()
End If
```

This should prevent the DGV from getting the keypress

Comment: I've actually tried that approach minus the DeleteCurrentRow() call but it didn't look like it helped so I rem'd it out. I'll give that another try and see.  Also, I've updated my post to reflect the newly added sub.

Comment: just set `AllowUserToDeleteRows = False` since you have code to run to check things

Comment: I put it in the wrong sub at first but now its in the keydown handler and works great. The bottom of my code shows the missing boolean expression.